# Android studio: how to properly use the support library AppCompat?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I know there are many versions such as v4, v7, v8, v13, v14, v17, etc and they aren't in order of upgrades. What I don't understand is the meaning of this checkbox in Android Studio when you create a new project and choose an empty activity

> Backwards compatibility (AppCompat)

The description says

> if false, this activity will be Activity instead of AppCompatActivity

It's a bit foggy to me, then I checked the library and I found out that it was  android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

The descriptions says that

> v7 Support Libraries
>   There are several libraries designed to be used with Android 2.3 (API level 9) and higher.

Again I don't understand whether I have to use it or not, depending on different cases. If I set the maximum target API, what is the necessary minSdk to not use it?

Comment: what is the min sdk version of your app which you are supposed to build and distribute?

Comment: It's the opposite: what min sdk version should we use in order to avoid the support library?

Answer (score 1):

It is not simple to answer your question.

The Support Libraries provide a wide range of classes for building apps, from fundamental app components, to user interface widgets, to media handling, to TV app components.

**Many of the classes are backward compatible implementations, but some of them are new features in their own right.**

It is very important this step. Not all support libraries are used to support backward implementation.

For example in your application you will need to use some components like:

- RecyclerView
- CardView
- ViewPager
- Design Library
- .....

In particular the design support library has a dependency with the appcompat library.

**It means that you can't avoid** the use of the support libraries only using a minSdk. Or in other words you have to use them always.

Here more info about the [support libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, when you opt out support libraries, you can not get benefit of the powerful [RecyeclerView, CardView, DesignSupportLib](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html) etc. Because these libs are dependent on `appCompat`

---

> what version should we use in order to avoid the support library?

You can use any version as min sdk version. It does not matter. Support lib is included in every project by default by android studio, you have to remove it manually.

> How to create new project without support library?

- While creating a new project,set min sdk version as 14 (just for example), don't add
  any activities during the wizard dialog. Just create a project with
  no activities. Then after you can add code as you wish
- You can remove the support library , removing the dependency from your `build.gradle`

  ```
   dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
  }
  ```
- Replace your theme parent in styles.xml into a non AppCompat version like `Holo.Light`

[image]

Comment: The answer is not correct. There are many support libraries, not only appcompat. You can't avoid using the recyclerview for example using minSdk = 21.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti updated my answer, op don't want to use any of the  appcomat libs like recyclerview, supportv7 etc..  i think so.

Comment: They are necessary in most cases, so I should use the AppCompatActivity, not the Activity class, am I right?

Comment: @user3290180 you should always use AppCompatActivity, it will make your life easier